# Adding photo to application form in asp

Tags: forms, file, asp-classic, upload

I have a student application form in an asp site that saves information to a SQL database. I want to add a photo field to the application form in order to upload photos to a specific folder in my server with a specific name. I add ***input type="file"*** code but I don't know how to define what will be the name of photo and in which folder it will be saved after upload. I have functions.asp that has the functions and default.asp that defines the actions. What should I add to these files?

Answer (score 0):

You must view AspJpeg component [this link](http://www.aspjpeg.com/manual_03.html). If your server has this component you must use this easily.